# Quickblocks receive video call crash

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture, quickblox

I am trying integrate quick blocks in swift.Everythings working fine but when i receive call request from other user my app getting crashed .i am getting this error

> [CAMetalLayerDrawable texture] should not be called after already
>   presenting this drawable. Get a nextDrawable instead.

and my QBRTCClientDelegate is like follows

```
func session(_ session: QBRTCBaseSession, receivedRemoteVideoTrack videoTrack: QBRTCVideoTrack, fromUser userID: NSNumber) {

    if (session as! QBRTCSession).id == self.session?.id {

         self.remoteView = QBRTCRemoteVideoView.init()
         self.remoteView?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect.rawValue
         self.remoteView?.clipsToBounds = true
         self.remoteView?.setVideoTrack(videoTrack)
         self.remoteView?.tag = userID.intValue
         self.stackView.addArrangedSubview((self.remoteView)!)


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?. I am facing the same problem

Comment: @पवन  which version  of Quickblocks SDK   are you using now

Comment: I had to  change the pod version to this 
 pod 'QuickBlox', '~> 2.15'
pod 'Quickblox-WebRTC', '~> 2.6.3' six months back i don't know whether this issue has been resolved in the latest version or not just give it a try and let me know

Comment: I used the latest version and still not fixed. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Metal only available with A7 processors or higher. I can suggest you force OpenGLES drawings instead of Metal, for now, just do this:

```
QBRTCRemoteVideoView.preferMetal = NO
```